# get wrong value after convert date to day

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert date (29/04/2017) to day in week but I get wrong value (Thursday, but need to be Saturday). I check the time of the server, all correct.
my code:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("29/04/2017");
$day = date('l', $timestamp);
echo $day;
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: change the / to - and you'll get your Saturday

Answer (score 1):

When you use slashes in your date, `strtotime()` assumes MM/DD/YYYY. You either need to change the format of your date or use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse the date

```
$timestamp = strtotime("04/29/2017");
$day = date('l', $timestamp);
echo $day;
```

or

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y, '29/04/2017);
$day = $date->format('l');
echo $day;
```

Comment: How can I conver the date in format dd/mm/yyyy to day?

Comment: it seems that my php version not support this syntax :(

Comment: What version of PHP are you  using? The first example is supported in all versions of PHP. The second has been supported since PHP 5.2 which has been obsolete for years

Comment: @JohnConde OP's acceptance record isn't so hot. I think they took the money and run.

Comment: Looks like we may need to leave a comment informing them of how to accept answers and why it is important to how this site works

Comment: *Meh*, you've done your good deed for the day ;-) I was going to post an answer before you popped in; I took a quick glance first.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to go with option 1 then